# How to create a PostgreSQL table from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, npgsql

I have installed [Npgsql](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql), a PostgreSQL package for .NET, and I wasn't successful in creating a table using the basic code snippet provided on GitHub. Here's my code

```csharp
using Npgsql;

string connectionString = "Host=localhost;" +
    "Username=postgres;" +
    "Password=mypassword;" +
    "Database=CSharp";
await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
await conn.OpenAsync();

await using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS drinking_water" +
    "(Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY," +
    "Date DATE," +
    "Quantity INTEGER", conn)) ;
```

When I start my Console Application, nothing happens.

Comment: You should follow that code up with something like command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() to invoke the command.

Answer (score 0):

As written above, you need to execute the command you've created. See the Npgsql [basic usage](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html) docs for an introduction on using Npgsql.